# Запись в бутсектор и вывод строки на экран без ОС

Tags: ассемблер, x86

Решил попробовать вывести строку, не используя ОС. Скомпилировал как .COM - всё работает, засунул код в бут-сектор флешки и пробовал запустить при старте машини - не работает. Интересно то, что на моей машине не работает, а пробовал на других - всё успешно запускается. Как это объяснить ?

```
org 7C00h

main:

    mov ax, 0x0000  ; Setup the Data Segment register
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 0x0E    ; The function to display a chacter (teletype)
    mov bh, 0x00    ; Page number
    mov bl, 0x07    ; Normal text attribute

    mov si, 0; array counter

    c1: 
        mov al, message[si]; copying character
        int 10h; call the BIOS interrupt (output characters on the screen)

        inc si; move on to the next character

        cmp message[si], 0; is zero ?

    jnz c1; if I did not reach zero in an array, then loop back to the beginning

    jmp $

ret

    message db "Hello, World!", 0

    db 510-($-main) dup(0)
    db 0x55, 0xaa

end main
```

Comment: Вы не забыли `push cs / pop ds`? И вы не устанавливаете `bx`. Ассемблер не любит неаккуратности.

Comment: .model tiny; а bx зачем ?

Comment: Это у com-файла model tiny, а бут-сектору кто сегменты настроит?

Насчёт BX: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm

Comment: ага! понял. спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Отпишитесь, если получится.

Comment: @nullptr, а Вы [boot hellworld tutorial](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/hello-world-boot-loader), который Вам советовали в ответе на другой вопрос, прочитали?

Там кроме регистра **ds** еще и **bl** с **bh** устанавливают, а также вместо выхода из main рекомендуют бесконечный цикл.

И вообще, довольно много всяких мелочей, связанных с boot объясняют.

Comment: да, спасибо. я учел уже все проколы, попробую как-нибудь на досуге поправить и протестить

Answer (score 1):

С "на моей машине не работает, а пробовал на других - всё успешно запускается" возникает идея о том, что ваш BIOS проверяет таблицу разметки MBR на целостность.

Comment: Очень даже может быть, потому что я в бут-сектор писал только код, а информацию про разделы не добавлял. Попробую добавить разделы и отпишу, что получиться.

Comment: Не работает